# Change count from increasing to decreasing in the tinymce footer

Tags: tinymce

It is possible to change the display there in the lower right corner, I managed to put a character limit, at the moment the count is increasing but I need it to be a countdown[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmEe0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve by deactivating the character counter plugin and then I created a function that counts the characters typed and subtracts from the maximum allowed value and then I started displaying this value in the statusbar with the decreasing quote.